# Format custom types with ostream

Tags: c++, ostream

We can change the stream behaviour with different options:

```
std::cout << 0xfabadau << '\n';
std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(8) << 0xfabadau << '\n';
```

Outputs:

> ```
> 16431834
> 00fabada
> ```

Now lets say I have a `byte_buffer` custom type:

```
using byte        = std::uint8_t;
using byte_buffer = std::vector<byte>;

std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const byte_buffer &buffer)
{
    for (const auto &b : buffer) o << std::hex << int{b};
    return o << std::dec;
}
```

Using it I cannot apply custom format::

```
byte_buffer b { 0xfau, 0xbau, 0xdau, };
std::cout << b << '\n';
std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(8) << b << '\n';
```

The code above shows the following output:

> ```
> fabada
> 000000fabada
> ```

The `std::setfill` and `std::setw` **outside of** the `std::ostream &operator <<` is affecting the first `byte` of `byte_buffer` **inside of** the `std::ostream &operator <<` hence the observed output, this isn't unexpected byt is not what I want. The output I want is:

> ```
> fabada
> 00fabada
> ```

---

How should I change the `std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const byte_buffer &buffer)` in order to make `byte_buffer` behave the way I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with byte something like this

```
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const byte_buffer &buffer)
{
    std::uint32_t temp=0;
    for (const auto &b : buffer)
    {
        temp<<=8;
        temp|=b;
    }
    return o << std::hex << temp << std::dec;
}
```

More flexible approach

```
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const byte_buffer &buffer)
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    for (const auto &b : buffer)
    {
        ss<< std::hex << int{b};
    }
    return o << ss.str();
}
```

Comment: This is a very interesting approach :) but it wouldn't work with arbitrary-lenght buffers (imagine a `byte_buffer` with length greter than 4, 8, 16, 666...).

Answer (score 2):

You can always get the flags and use them in your function however you want. For example (only dealing with the width here)

```
int width = o.width(), item_width;
int fill = o.fill();
if (width > 2*buffer.size())
  item_width = width - 2*(buffer.size()-1);
else
  item_width = 2;
for (const auto &b : buffer) 
{
   o << std::hex << std::setw(item_width) << setfill(fill) << int{b};
   item_width = 2; fill = '0';
}
```